# How to display date in a middleman article page

Tags: middleman

I'm developing a blog with middle man, I write the articles in markdown. Below is a sample article `2016-01-27-small-and-large-balcony-ideas.html.md`

```
---
title: Small and large balcony ideas
category: "balcony ideas"
---

# Small and large balcony ideas
```

It uses the following layout `layouts/blog.erb`

```
<body class="<%= page_classes %>">

    <%= partial "blog_header" %>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column column-75">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <div class="column column-25">
          <%= partial "blog_sidebar" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= partial "blog_footer" %>
</body>
```

Now when I go to the `article.url` the page displays heading and the content straightaway. I want to display the article date above or below the main heading. How can I do that.

Comment: Do you have the `blog_header` definition? I'd try to add a `date` field in the header - or infer the date by parsing the article name.

Comment: the `blog_header` is used to list articles as well so it might throw an error in case of collection of articles

Answer (score 0):

I add:

```
<p><%= current_article.date.strftime('%d %B %Y') %></p>
```

into my layout just above

```
<%= yield %>
```

Is that what you are looking for?